# Finding a missing .bash_profile

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

About a year ago I wanted to edit .bash_profile to add some text when I opened Terminal (I'm on a Mac with the latest OS). Today, I wanted to change that text, only to find that I couldn't find the original file I edited. It seems like MacPorts moved something around, because I can add text on the .bash_profile file, but the original text I made last year isn't in the file, and I can't delete it.

This is my current .bash_profile:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"

##
# Your previous /Users/nathanielhoffman/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/nathanielhoffman/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2015-10-11_at_12:31:11
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-10-11_at_12:31:11: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

And before you ask, yes, I've checked .profile and .bashrc. Nothing there. Nothing in that backup profile MacPorts said it had made either. Adding text like 'echo "hello world" ' at the end of this file will add that text under the mystery text source.

Is there a way I can figure out which file my computer is reading when it first opens up a shell? Thanks in advance!

Comment: MacPorts will usually backup your .bash_profile before making any changes to a file such as `.bash_profile.macports-saved_2015-01-20_at_19:08:40`

Comment: The problem is, the only lines in that file are:

Comment: PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Version/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

Comment: Which is not the text I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can figure out which file my computer is reading when it first opens up a shell?

You can set `PS4` which is used when running bash in debug `-x`:

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO: ' bash -xlic ""
```

This will give you a trace of what files are sourced including command and line number when starting bash as an interactive login shell.

`-x` traces, `-l` is login shell, `-i` is interactive and `-c ''` is the command to run.

See `man bash` for info about `PS4`:

```
   PS4    The  value  of  this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and the value
          is printed before each command bash displays during an execution trace.
          The first character of PS4 is replicated multiple times, as necessary,
          to indicate multiple levels of indirection. The default is ``+ ''.
```

Comment: This led me on a wild adventure through my /etc/ folder. After looking through everything that had "bash" or "profile" in the name, I finally noticed a file called "motd" which I figured stood for "message of the day". Low and behold, the text I was searching for was there. Thank you.